# Visibility of stacked HTML popups

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a jQuery Backbone.js web app.
I have a table with table entries. The table has a white background.
If the user selects a table entry, a modal popup is shown. To show the user that the popup is now in modal mode, I used to have the jQuery UI diagonal stripes (ui-widget-overlay).

But I changed to an alternative. Those stripes were too "striking", "obtrusive" for me. I now change the opacity of the table to 0.5. I like this more.

The problem now is that I have popups in the popup window. And if I also change the opacity of the first popup to show the user that only the second popup is working now, the table shines through the first popup.

Is there any possibility, any alternative way to have a popup window (a div) "dim", "grey out" to half of its appearance without getting transparent?

Comment: what do you mean by alternative for opacity? You can have opacity or not. That is like asking for an alternative for text.

Comment: btw: opening multiple popups will most probably degrade the user experience. Perhaps you should think about an alternative workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add another div on top of the div that has the same dimensions but has grey background color with opacity 0.75. This should work pretty fine.

**CSS**

```
.inner {
  position: absolute;
}

.fade {
 background: grey;
 opacity: 0.75;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">content</div>
 <div class="inner fade"></div>
</div>​
```

This way you are pretty safe when it comes to cross-browser references. Also you can control the fade by adding an "id" attribute to the fade class and make it go away. This way, you can also make div inactive, as they div inner fade is on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with hsla ([look here](http://css-tricks.com/yay-for-hsla/)).

```
<style>
#el1 {
    background: red;
     width: 700px;
     height: 700px;
}

#el2 { 
     background-color: hsla(190, 30%, 94%, 0.6); 
     width: 500px;
     height: 500px;
}

#el3 { 
     background: green;
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
}
</style>

<div id="el1">
    <div id="el2">
        <div id="el3">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my code, el1 is the holder and not transparent at all. Then, el2 as first child uses hsla for transparency. The contained el3 is not transparent again and this works.

Answer (score 0):

You could lay a glass pane on top of your page and set the z-index appropriately so that your 2nd popup lies on top of it and everything else is hidden under it:

```
#pane {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Assure that your 2nd popup has a z-index higher than the pane and you're fine.